# drawBitmap is showing picture bigger than it is

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Here's the sample of the code I've been using to show a part of an image on a canvas:

```
Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thecat);
//the cat is 600x600 single image that looks like a 3x3 table made of 200x200 images

Bitmap smallShaft = Bitmap.createBitmap(map, 200, 200, 200, 200);
//notice createBitmap(source, startX, startY, width, height)

Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(); 
    c.drawARGB(255, 124, 124, 255);
    c.drawBitmap(smallShaft, 0,0, null); 
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

And what I get is a 200x200 square that contains over-sized image. Despite I cut the 200x200 part off of an 600x600 image, it shows like I cut 200x200 part off of an (600*1.5)x(600*1.5) image.

What I get

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/pb2Qv.png]

Where I'm cutting from

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/HRESU.jpg]

One more detail you should know maybe. 
It's been drawn on custom SurfaceView that implements Runnable and image is being redrawn in infinite loop.